# Validate and compare datetime before inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following scenario, where I want to store the customer phone number for callback only ONCE within 4 hours, in the sense if the customer request a callback again and again within the 4 hours then the system will check if there is a request already being created in the database, if yes then do not create the request otherwise, create the callback.

Please note that I'm using a `datetime` column in this format "2021-03-14 23:50:34.263"

I have used the below but it's only validating the mobileNo:

```
INSERT INTO AppointmentsList(mobileNo)
SELECT 'mobileNo'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT mobileNo
    FROM AppointmentsList
    WHERE mobileNo = 'mobileNo'
)
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Examples of valid data to be inserted an invalid data would help.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You SQL isn't comparing the date? And `'mobileNo'` is literally the string 'mobileNo' - its not *the* mobile number which I assume is in a variable somewhere.

Comment: `datetime` values are binary values. The "format" you're talking about is presentation format. Also, your query doesn't appear to do any comparison with a `datetime` column.

Comment: There's a datetime column which is auto generated whenever the mobileNo is inserted, and I want to compare if the mobileNo is already exist if yes check the datetime column if it's greater than 4 hours from the current time then insert otherwise reject the request.

Comment: So what are you stuck on? You don't even show a date compare in your query, and you don't show a proper mobile number either. SQL Server has a bunch of datetime functions which may help, they are all listed in the documentation. One also wonders how you mark an appointment complete - I can't imagine you delete there record, so I would be expected another compare to ensure its an incomplete appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a MERGE statement suits here

You'll probably need to play with date format but I'll try to make the idea clear

```
merge into AppointmentsList al
using(select '+123456' mobileNo, '20210314 10:00:00 AM' some_date) new_data
   on al.mobileNo = new_data.mobileNo 
  and datediff(hour, new_data.some_date, al.some_date) < 4
when not matched then insert(mobileNo, some_date) 
                      values(new_data.mobileNo, new_data.some_date);
```

Just pass new phone number and data within "new_data" sub-query